# how to make auto character feature for the textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea

In good IDE its common the when you press `'` (single quotes ) then the another is automatically added to it, so i tried to make it for the textarea so here is my code by it is not working::

```
var ele = document.getElementById('main');
ele.onkeypress = function(e){
  switch(e.keyCode){
      case 59: ele.innerHTML+=";"; break;
      case 39: ele.innerHTML+="'"; break;
      case 47: ele.innerHTML+='/'; break;
      case 91: ele.innerHTML+=']'; break;
      case 123: ele.innerHTML+='}'; break;
      case 45: ele.innerHTML+='-'; break;
  }
    console.log(e);
}
```

### HTML

```
<textarea id="main"></textarea>
```

well `console.log(e)` is working, it is loging as many times i press key in textarea and it is working but for only one time that is if i open the page containing all these code in the browser (i am using Google Chrome, latest) and when for the first time if and only if i press key whose code is listed in the switch case then it works but after that it is not functional however `console.log(e)` is functioning every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textarea elements don't have HTML content, so `innerHTML` won't do what you expect. You should use `value` property instead:

```js
var ele = document.getElementById('main');
ele.onkeypress = function(e){
  switch(e.keyCode){
      case 59: ele.value += ";"; break;
      case 39: ele.value += "'"; break;
      case 47: ele.value += '/'; break;
      case 93: ele.value += ']'; break;
      case 125: ele.value += '}'; break;
      case 45: ele.value += '-'; break;
  }
  console.log(e.keyCode);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="main"></textarea>
```